# svn how to replace trunk with feature branch for one repository

Tags: svn

my situation is I have many repositories in trunk.
And I have one repo (repoA) in both trunk FEATURE branch.

I just want to copy all code for my repoA from FEATURE branch to trunk branch and commit.

what is the right way to do this?
can I just simply copy the folder? Or do I do something like this:

```
sandbox$ svn up -r ANOTHER_BRANCH
```

?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `svn up` takes the **current** checked out URL, and updates it. If it's trunk, it'll be trunk.

There are two possible things you're talking about:

1. You want to replace the code on your currently checked out client directory with the code from the branch.
2. You want to replace the trunk on your server with the code on your branch.

The first one will only affect the files checked out on your machine. If someone else checks out trunk, they'll get the current trunk, and not the feature branch.

The second one replaces the trunk with the feature branch. Others who checkout the code will now see the same code that was on feature branch.

So, which do you want to do?

I'm going to assume you want to change the code on your system to point to the feature branch, so you can work on the feature branch:

```
$ svn switch $SERVER_URL/branches/another_branch
```

Pretty simple. This will update your current working directory with the files from the branch, and will change the checkout URL pointing to that branch. It will also keep changes you've made, so it's not a clean checkout.

This is helpful in case you've made a mistake where you had trunk checked out, and did some work, then realize you needed these changes not against trunk, but against a branch.

Normally, I discourage the use of `svn switch`. When you have computers that come with a minimum of 250Gb of space, there's just not much reason to share a working directory with several branches and the trunk. I worry about the mixup and confusion that results in forgetting which branch or trunk you're working on and checking in your changes in the wrong location.

Even really, really big projects don't take that long to checkout in Subversion, and once you've checked out the project, you'll never have to do that again. Simple updates will suffice. So, you're not saving all that much time or diskspace.

What I've seen is someone checks out `$REPO_URL/trunk` in order to work on their project `$REPO_URL/trunk/foo` and ends up checking out dozens of other projects they simply don't need.

In fact, because I dabble across dozens of projects, I usually want to check out the entire trunk or branch, but just don't want all the files until I need them:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/workdir/repo_name
$ cd ~/workdir/repo_name
$ svn co --depth=immediates $SERVER_URL/repo_name/trunk
```

This will checkout all of the projects on trunk, but none of the files. The `--depth` command allows you to do *sparse checkouts* where you can select the flies you need. For example, I need to work on project `foo` and `bar`:

```
$ cd ~/workdir/repo_name/trunk
$ svn up --set-depth=infinity foo bar
```

I can do the same thing on branch `foobar`:

```
$ cd ~/workdir/repo_name
$ svn co --depth=immediates $SERVER_URL/repo_name/foobar
$ cd foobar
$ svn up --set-depth=infinity foo bar
```

Now, I can look at my current working directory and see what repo and branch I'm on, and know I'm in the right place. The only issue is that since Subversion 1.7, I can't run a `svn` command in `foo` if I am running a `svn` command in `bar that's taking a while to process.